# asp.net jquery change html inside updatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, updatepanel

I've got UpdatePanel with Div

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxPanel1">
 <div class="pnlFind" style="display:none;"> 
 </div>
 </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

wanna use js for showing this div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
     if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
         $('.btAddUser').click(function () {
             $('.pnlFind').show('slow');
             $('.pnlFind').attr('display', 'block');
             return false;
         });
     }
 }
</script>
```

but after partial postback, I got div invisible again(right! restore DOM) How can I remember that div should be always visible after button click. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject javascript into the page to simulate the click event again.  Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock or Page.RegisterStartUpScript should do it.

Comment: sorry, I don't understad how can I simulate click event again?

Comment: then make another function with you .btAddUser code in it and call that.  Change your original event (Above) to call it as well so you don't duplicate code.